# Is the weighted sum of subset prefix product problem NP-hard?

Tags: np-hardness, np-complete

I have this strange problem where we have a set of positive numbers $M$, a fixed number $n$, and a function $f: M \rightarrow R^+$ mapping each number in M to another positive number. We want to know if we can select non-repetitive numbers $a_1, \cdots, a_n \in M$, such that the sum over weighted prefix product $\sum_{i=1}^n f(a_i) \cdot \prod_{j=1}^{i} a_j$ is maximized. Does anyone know if this is NP-hard?

Edit: What about for some fixed $m \in [n]$ and $p \in (0, 1)$, maximizing $\sum_{i=1}^m f(a_i) \cdot \prod_{j=1}^{i} a_j + p \cdot \sum_{i=m+1}^n f(a_i) \cdot \prod_{j=1}^{i} a_j$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Theorem 1.** *The problem has an $O(m\log m)$-time algorithm, where $m=|M|$.*

*Proof sketch.*
Fix an instance of the problem.
Assume without loss of generality that $M\subseteq (0, 1)$.
(Otherwise an optimal solution $a_1,\ldots, a_n$ for $M$
can be obtained by computing an optimal solution $a'_1, a'_2, \ldots, a'_{n'}$ for $M'=M\cap (0, 1)$,
then prepending the elements in $M\cap [1, \infty)$ in decreasing order.)

By rewriting, the problem is equivalent to finding
$p=(p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n) \subseteq M$ maximizing
$$\text{value}(p) = \sum_{i=1}^n \big(\textstyle\prod_{j=1}^{i-1} p_j\big)  (1-p_i) g(p_i),~~~~~~~~~(1)$$
where $g(z) = f(z)z/(1-z)$.

---

*Remark for intuition.* This interpretation is nice because then $\text{value}(p)$ is the expectation of the value returned by the following random process:

1. for $i \gets 1, 2, \ldots, n$:
2. $~~~$ with probability $1-p_i$, halt and return $g(p_i)$ (otherwise (with probability $p_i$) continue)
3. return 0

With this interpretation, it is not too hard to see that we should use *all* elements of $M$ (in some order), and further that we should use them greedily---in order of decreasing $g(p_i)$.
The proof below gives the details.

---

Here is the algorithm:

1. let $q=(q_1, q_2, \ldots, g_m)$ be $M$ sorted by decreasing $g(q_i)$ (breaking ties arbitrarily).
2. return $q$

Clearly this can be done in $O(m\log m)$ time.
To finish we show that $q$ is an optimal solution.

By inspection of (1), there is an optimal solution
that uses all elements of $M$ (as appending unused elements
to any solution cannot decrease the cost).
Let $p=(p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_m)$ be any such optimal solution.
Define an *inversion* in $p$ to be a pair $i, j\in [m]$
such that $i < j$ and $r(i) > r(j)$,
where $r(i)$ is the rank of $p_i$ in $q$
(so $q_{r(i)} = p_i$).
If there are no inversions, then $p=q$ so $q$ is optimal, and we are done.
Otherwise, there is an inversion $(i, i+1)$.
Consider modifying $p$ by swapping $p_i$ with $p_{i+1}$.
By calculation, this swap
increases the solution value by $\prod_{j=1}^{i-1} p_j$ times
$$
\begin{aligned}
   &(1-p_{i+1}) g(p_{i+1})+ p_{i+1} (1-p_i) g(p_i) \\
 {}-{} & p_i (1-p_{i+1}) g(p_{i+1}) - (1-p_i) g(p_i) \\
 {}={} & [g(p_{i+1}) - g(p_i)] (1-p_i)(1-p_{i+1}) \\
 {}\ge{} & 0 & (\text{using } r(i) > r(i+1), \text{ so } g(p_i) \le g(p_{i+1})).
\end{aligned}
$$
So this swap reduces the number of inversions by one
and yields another optimal solution.
So repeatedly swapping yields an optimal solution $p$ with no inversions, i.e., with $p=q$, so $q$ is optimal.$~~~~\Box$

Comment: Thank you so much for this thorough response! I wasn't sure if it was easy or hard at first glance.

Comment: Sure.  One thing: in general it improves posts to add some context about where the problem comes from, what you've tried, and so on.  See https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help for more advice.

Comment: Yeah this makes sense! I will give more context in the future. (The original problem I was considering was that there are a bunch of boxes, each one with probability $p_i$ has a prize of value $h_i$, and remaining probability with nothing. Our task is to order them in advance and then inspect them one by one, once we see a prize we have to take it and leave. When we can order them however we like it's clear we should inspect box in decreasing $h_i$, but what if some of the boxes have fixed position that we cannot change? The special case of 1-box fixed can be converted to my posted Q. )

Comment: (Our objective is to have the highest expected prize value.)

Comment: Interesting.  How can the case with one box fixed be reduced to your posted question?  If you'd like to ask about the more general question, I guess you can make another post.

Comment: Sorry turns out I made a mistake in my calculation and the one box version is not exactly equivalent to what I described (f(1- p_i) sometimes depend on the position of the box and not just the value p_i). I posted my original problem in another post (posting the link here in case you are interested). https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/51247/prize-box-ordering-problem-with-position-constraints-easy-or-hard